# Pass class instance from jsp to servlet

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, servlets

Hi I need to show a list of "categories" on jsp page from DB and user should be able to remove any row.

1. I've created a Category class.
2. To be able to pass list of Cetogories to jsp I've created a "CategoryListBean":

   ```
   public class CategoryListBean {
     private List<Category> categories;
     public List<Category> getCategories() {
       return categories;
     }
     public void setCategories(List<Category> categories) {
       this.categories = categories;
     }
   }
   ```

and in my jsp:

```
    <jsp:useBean id="listCategory" class="beans.CategoryListBean" scope="request"/>
    ...
    <c:forEach items="${listCategory.categories}" var="item">
      <tr>
        <td>${item.name}</td>
        <td>${item.description}</td>
        <td>
          <form action="RemoveCategory" method="post">
            <input type="submit" value="Remove">
          </form>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </c:forEach>
```

How can my "RemoveCategory" servlet understand which item user want to be deleted?
Yes, I can pass some parameter like "itemId = item.Id" but I'm using Hibernate to comunicate with DB and I think, I need to get an instance of "Category" class to write something like this:

```
(Hibernate) session.beginTransaction();
(Hibernate) session.delete(categoryInstance);
(Hibernate) session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Can I use

```
    <input type="hidden" name="item" value=${item}>
```

in my jsp form for that? And if i can, how can i get this parameter in my servlet?

Thanks

Comment: Send the id. Before deleting, retrieve the object to check if it still exists and then delete it and reload the updated list

Comment: In my BD each Category contains some subCategories. So, if I will follow your scenario I'm gonna need two hibernate Queries: 1 - remove all sub categories; 2 - remove category. It's much simplier to retrieve class instance and remove everything by one line "session.delete(categoryInstance);"

Comment: Cascade on delete and lazy relationships

Comment: That's my first Java Web project and I've already realized that I'm a complete idiot. I'm not shure that I completely understood... Can you provide some code example (or useful links) for me, please?

Comment: Oh, i already have an annotation @OneToMany(targetEntity=Item.class, mappedBy="category", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.Lazy) On getItems() method. But when i'm trying to execute session.createQuery("delete Category WHERE categoryId = :categoryId"); Postgre sais: "I can't delete becasuse you've got some subCategories related"

Comment: Use the entity manager to delete